# How to stop any action if index of array is not available in count

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm displaying objects from the array. example :

```
export default function App() {
  const data = [
    { id: 1, more: "string 1" },
    { id: 2, more: "string 2" },
    { id: 3, more: "string 3" }
  ];
  // here if index becomes 4 it breaks as there is no object in the data with index 4 
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0); 
  const submitHandler = () => {
  // probably there we need any type of if statement but I don't; know how to compare with index
    setIndex(index + 1);
  };

  const showDat = (data, index) => {
    return <p>{data[index].more}</p>;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container>
        <Col md={8}>
          <Card style={{ minHeight: "40rem" }}>
            {showDat(data, index)}
            <Card.Footer>
              <Button
                variant="outline-danger"
                onClick={submitHandler}
                className="mx-1"
              >
                {" "}
                Skip
              </Button>
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={submitHandler}>
                {" "}
                Continue
              </Button>
            </Card.Footer>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is if index is not available in the array then code breaks and I want to add error handling, like if index is not equal then make the continue button disable or something like that.

So how can I compare the count of index of the array to index state ?
Running Example in [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-kare-z2mk6c?file=/src/App.js:115-1095)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `disabled={data.length - 1 === index}` in 2 buttons to disable them whenever the index is at max of data length

Full change

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Container, Col, Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const data = [
    { id: 1, more: "string 1" },
    { id: 2, more: "string 2" },
    { id: 3, more: "string 3" }
  ];

  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const submitHandler = () => {
    setIndex(index + 1);
  };

  const showDat = (data, index) => {
    return <p>{data[index].more}</p>;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container>
        <Col md={8}>
          <Card style={{ minHeight: "40rem" }}>
            {showDat(data, index)}
            <Card.Footer>
              <Button
                variant="outline-danger"
                onClick={submitHandler}
                className="mx-1"
                disabled={data.length - 1 === index}
              >
                {" "}
                Skip
              </Button>
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={submitHandler} disabled={data.length - 1 === index}>
                {" "}
                Continue
              </Button>
            </Card.Footer>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what if i have button who goes back, like const goBackHandler = () => {
    // go back
    setIndex(index - 1)
  }, Is there any way to handle more dynamically, what if I want to add more conditions other than disable button , I want any condition who returns true and false on comparison in the handlers

Comment: If you have `goBackHandler`, the disabling condition will be updated accordingly which means your buttons will be enabled again. For the complex conditions and not disabling buttons, you can have the condition in that handler like `const submitHandler = () => {
    if(data.length - 1 === index) { setIndex(index + 1); }
  };` @atropabelladona

Comment: you can check my implementation for `goBackHandler` with the condition https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-liskov-fjq5nw @atropabelladona

Answer (score 1):

```
            export default function App() {
              const data = [
                { id: 1, more: "string 1" },
                { id: 2, more: "string 2" },
                { id: 3, more: "string 3" }
              ];
              // here if index becomes 4 it breaks as there is no object in the data with index 4 
              const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0); 
              const submitHandler = () => {
              // probably there we need any type of if statement but I don't; know how to compare with index
             // This condition can prevent to crash the code, even though you can add your own logic here, or you can apply same functionality on "Continue" button disable attribute I had commented it on below button
              //if (index  < data.length-1)
                if (index + 1 < data.length)
                setIndex(index + 1);
              };
            
              const showDat = (data, index) => {
                return <p>{data[index].more}</p>;
              };
            
              return (
                <div className="App">
                  <Container>
                    <Col md={8}>
                      <Card style={{ minHeight: "40rem" }}>
                        {showDat(data, index)}
                        <Card.Footer>
                          <Button
                            variant="outline-danger"
                            onClick={submitHandler}
                            className="mx-1"
                          >
                            {" "}
                            Skip
                          </Button>
                          <Button 
                           disabled={index + 2 > data.length ? true 
                           : false} 
                           //disabled={index >= data.length - 1 ? 
                           true : false}
                           variant="primary"  
                           onClick={submitHandler}
                           >
                            {" "}
                            Continue
                          </Button>
                        </Card.Footer>
                      </Card>
                    </Col>
                  </Container>
                </div>
              );
            }
    
  Sandbox link :[CodeSandBox][1]


  [1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-oskar-t93mnx?file=/src/App.js
```